# Possible to perform an additional jquery selection on stored selector object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Example data:

```
<input class="foo" special="yes" value="1" new="yes">
<input class="foo" special="no" value="2" new="yes">
<input class="foo" value="3" new="red">
<input class="foo" special="yes" value="4">
<input class="foo" value="5" new="yes">
```

now the jquery:

```
var the_inputs = $("input.foo");
```

...will give me a jquery object of all the inputs.

I can also do:

```
var the_special_inputs = $("input.foo[special]");
```

... which returns only the inputs that have a special attribute.

Even further, I can get just the inputs that have a special attribute where they also have the attribute new of "yes":

```
var the_special_inputs = $("input.foo[special][new='yes']");
```

But what if I just wanted to use 'the_inputs' and create the var `the_special_inputs` without doing another selector? in there words, if I have the stored var:

```
var the_inputs = $("input.foo");
```

...is there a way to write an additional selector on that stored var that would give me the same results as `$("input.foo[special]");` or the others like above but JUST using `the_inputs` which was previously stored?

a few things I've tried that don't work:

```
$(the_inputs+"[special][new='yes']");
$("[special]",the_inputs);
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 11):

Use [jQuery's `.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
var the_inputs = $("input.foo");
var the_special_inputs = the_inputs.filter("[special][new='yes']");
```

This will create a new set that is the original reduced to those that match the selector you pass without having to do an additional DOM selection.

There's another method [called `.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) that retains those that do not match the selector.

Comment: awesome! thanks so much. great to know and doesnt seem to be used as often as it should, no?

Comment: @Oliver: If you mean using it in order to avoid redundant DOM selections, then I'd tend to agree. I'm very much in favor of caching a selection and referencing it (or parts of it) as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method as well, but filter is much better :

```
var the_inputs = $("input.foo");
var the_special_inputs = the_inputs.find("[special][new='yes']");
```

Comment: In this case, the `.find()` method wouldn't actually work. `.find()` is used to search for descendants. In this case, OP wants to reduce the matched set, so you need to apply a selector to the matched set itself. That's the main difference between the two. `.find()` looks *inside* the elements, while `.filter()` looks *among* the elements. :o)